# How to embed html into Data Studio

Tags: html, url, plotly, looker-studio

I have a motion bubble chart written using plotly and output in html. How can I embed that chart into Google Data Studio? I only know the option of embed url in Data Studio report but I don't know how to convert html into url and where to host that url link in order to embed it in Data Studio.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!